# Tangent line of parametric curve

Tags: calculus, integration

I have not seen a problem like this so I have no idea what to do.

Find an equation of the tangent to the curve at the given point by two methods, without elimiating parameter and with.

$$x = 1 + \ln t,\;\; y = t^2 + 2;\;\; (1, 3)$$

I know that $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{\; 2t\; }{\dfrac{1}{t}}$$

But this give a very wrong answer. I am not sure what a parameter is or how to eliminate it.

Answer (score 6):

1. **Eliminating the parameter** $t$. The given system of two parametric equations $$\begin{eqnarray*}\left\{ 
   \begin{array}{c}
   x=1+\ln t \\ 
   y=t^{2}+2
   \end{array}
   \right. \end{eqnarray*} \tag{A}$$ is equivalent successively to
   $$\begin{eqnarray*}
   \left\{ 
   \begin{array}{c}
   x-1=\ln t \\ 
   y=t^{2}+2
   \end{array}
   \right. \Leftrightarrow \left\{ 
   \begin{array}{c}
   t=e^{x-1} \\ 
   y=t^{2}+2
   \end{array}
   \right.  
   \Leftrightarrow \left\{ 
   \begin{array}{c}
   t=e^{x-1} \\ 
   y=\left( e^{x-1}\right) ^{2}+2
   \end{array}
   \right. \end{eqnarray*}$$ and finally to $$\left\{ 
   \begin{array}{c}
   t=e^{x-1} \\ 
   y=e^{2\left( x-1\right) }+2.
   \end{array}
   \right. \tag{B}
   $$
   We have thus eliminated the parameter $t$. 
   Here is a plot of $y=e^{2\left( x-1\right) }+2$
   [image]
   Differentiating the equation of the curve $$y=e^{2\left( x-1\right) }+2\tag{C}$$ gives by the chain rule applied to $e^u$, with $u=2(x-1)$
   $$\begin{eqnarray*}
   \frac{dy}{dx} &=&\frac{d}{dx}\left( e^{2\left( x-1\right) }+2\right) =\frac{d
   }{dx}e^{2\left( x-1\right) }=\left( \frac{
   d}{du}e^{u}\right) \frac{du}{dx} 
   =e^{u}\times 2=2e^{2\left( x-1\right) }.
   \end{eqnarray*}$$
   At $x=1$ this derivative has the value 
   $$\begin{equation*}
   \left. \frac{dy}{dx}\right\vert _{x=1}=\left. 2e^{2\left( x-1\right)
   }\right\vert _{x=1}=2e^{2(1-1)}=2.\tag{1}
   \end{equation*}$$
   Since at $x=1$, $$y=e^{2(1-1)}+2=3,$$ we have confirmed that the point $(x,y)=(1,3)$ belongs to the graph of the curve given by equation $(C)$. Hence the equation of the tangent line to the graph of the curve at $(1,3)$ is
   $$\begin{equation*}
   y-3=2(x-1)\Leftrightarrow y=2x+1\tag{2}
   \end{equation*}$$
2. **Without eliminating the parameter** $t$. *(Reformulated in view of OP's comment.)* To compute the derivative we use now the parametric equations $(A)$ and the formula $$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}/\frac{dx}{dt}.\tag{D}$$  We have
   $$\begin{eqnarray*}
   \frac{dy}{dx} &=&\frac{dy}{dt}/\frac{dx}{dt}=
   \left( \frac{d}{dt}\left( t^{2}+2\right) \right) /\frac{d}{dt}\left( 1+\ln
   t\right)  \\
   &=&2t/\frac{1}{t}=2t^2,\tag{3}
   \end{eqnarray*}$$
   *which confirms your result*. Since for $x=1$ the equation $$x=1+\ln t $$ gives $$1=1+\ln t\Leftrightarrow 0=\ln t \Leftrightarrow t=1,$$   we get the same value as in $(1)$ for the derivative $$\begin{equation*}
   \left. \frac{dy}{dx}\right\vert _{x=1}=\left. 2t^2\right\vert
   _{t=1}=2\cdot 1^2=2.\tag{3a}
   \end{equation*}$$
   The equation of the tangent line is as above
   $$\begin{equation*}
   y=2x+1.\tag{4}
   \end{equation*}$$
   In terms of the parameter $t$ the tangent line at $t=1$, i.e. at $(x,y)=(1,3)$ is given by the parametric equations
   $$\begin{equation*}
   \left\{ 
   \begin{array}{c}
   x=t \\ 
   y=2t+1,
   \end{array}
   \right.\tag{4a} 
   \end{equation*}$$
   because
   $$\begin{equation*}
   \left. \frac{dx}{dt}\right\vert _{t=1}=\left. \frac{1}{t}\right\vert _{t=1}=1
   \end{equation*}$$
   and
   $$\begin{equation*}
   \left. \frac{dy}{dt}\right\vert _{t=1}=\left. 2t\right\vert _{t=1}=2.
   \end{equation*}$$

Comment: I don't quit follow part 2, in my book the equation is t$\frac{dy}{dt}/ \frac{dx}{dt}$ is this the same thing as that and why did you use this other identity?

Comment: @Jordan Yes. We can write $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}/\frac{dx}{dt}$

Comment: @Jordan I added the computation with $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}/\frac{dx}{dt}$

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is by considering the parametric form of the curve:
$(x,y)(t) = (1 + \log t, t^2 + 2)$, so $(x,y)'(t) = (\frac{1}{t}, 2t)$
We need to find the value of $t$ when $(x,y)(t) = (1 + \log t, t^2 + 2) = (1,3)$, from where we deduce $t=1$. The tangent line at $(1,3)$ has direction vector $(x,y)'(1) = (1,2)$, and since it passes by the point $(1,3)$ its parametric equation is given by: $s \mapsto (1,2)t + (1,3)$.

Another way (I suppose this is eliminating the parameter) would be to express $y$ in terms of $x$ (this can't be done for any curve, but in this case it is possible). We solve for $t$: $x = 1 + \log x \Rightarrow x = e^{x-1}$, so $y = t^2 + 2 = (e^{x-1})^2 + 2 = e^{2x-2} + 2$. The tangent line has slope $\frac{dy}{dx}=y_x$ evaluated at $1$: we have $y_x=2e^{2x-2}$ and $y_x(1)=2e^0 = 2$, so it the line has equation $y=2x +b$. Also, it passes by the point $(1,3)$, so we can solve for $b$: $3 = 2 \cdot 1 + b \Rightarrow b = 1$. Then, the equation of the tangent line is $y = 2x + 1$.

Note that $s \mapsto (1,2)t + (1,3)$ and $y = 2x + 1$ are the same line, expressed in different forms.

Comment: I have no idea what a direction vector is.

Comment: Sorry :  I  am   posting  my  answer  when  your  was  not  edited  yet !

Comment: If you have a line given in parametric form: $t \mapsto tA + B$, $A$ is called a direction vector of the line. Have you seen parametric equations of lines and curves?

Comment: This is my first time working with parametric equations.

Comment: @Mohamed Il n'y a pas de problème. :-)

Comment: @Jordan I suggest that you ask first about parametric equations, then. A little summary: suppose we have a way of describing the position of a particle in the plane at any time $t$, that is, we know $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ for any $t$. Then we could describe its trajectory by considering the function that maps a $t$ to the corresponding $(x(t),y(t))$, the corresponding point in the plane. A specific example: if the trajectory is given by $(x(t),y(t)) = (\cos t, \sin t)$, then the particle is moving counterclockwise  along a circumference of radius $1$. If $A$ and $B$ are fixed vectors, then ...

Comment: the parametric equation $(x(t),y(t)) = tA + B$ describes a rectilinear trajectory, i.e., a line in the plane. When we're looking for a tangent line of a curve given by a parametric equation, we'll start with any expression for $(x(t),y(t))$, and try to produce one for the tangent line, which will have the form $(x(t),y(t)) = tA + B$. In this exercise, $A=(1,2)$ and $B=(1,3)$.

Comment: @Jordon, in addition to what Talmid said, try this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m6c6dlmUT1c

Comment: Yes, that'll help much more than anything I can fit into one or two comments.

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1** Eliminating. I think they want to write everything in terms of x first.

$x = 1 + ln(t) \iff e^{x - 1} = t$

$y = t^2 + 2 = e^{2x -2} + 2 \implies y' = 2e^{2x -2}$

At (1,3) $y' = 2$. So the tangent line is $y = 2(x- 1) + 3$ or parametrically let $x - 1 = t 
\iff x = 1 + t$ and $y = 2t + 3$

**Method 2** No eliminating.

Let $r = (1 + ln(t),2 + t^2) \implies r' = (1/t, 2t)$. At (1,3), $t = 1$, therefore $r'(1) = (1,2)$

$r = (1,3) + s(1,2)$ which gives you $x = 1 + s$ and $y = 3 + 2s$

Comment: I do not understand the r subsitution, is this similar to finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: What substitution? You mean me writing it as r(t)?

Comment: You said "Let r ="

Comment: Yup, that's the vector valued equation of a line.

Comment: I have no idea what a vector value equation is.

Comment: My book gets $y= 2x+1$

Comment: Your book didn't write it as a parametric equation and in the first method I actually let $x = 1 + t$ instead of $x = t$ (which is probably a better choice since the Cartesian line simplifies so neatly). The second method will also give you the same line, but you have to eliminate the parameter $s$ to see

Answer (score 2):

2nd method: eliminating parameter:

$x=1+ \ln t , y=t^2+2 \Leftrightarrow  t=\exp(x-1), y=2+\exp(2x-2)$

Consider the function:  $f(x)=2+ \exp(2x-2)$, then: $f'(x)=2 \exp(2x-2)$

The  tangent at $x=1$ has equation: $Y=f'(1)(X-1)+ f(1)$, thus: $Y=2(X-1)+3$, thus:$$Y=2X+1$$